# Difference between LIGO and Michelson-Morley interferometer

Tags: optics, gravitational-waves, interferometry, ligo

The LIGO interferometer looks like a huge Michelson-Morley experiment showing interferences and the gravitational waves are described as waves propagating on the 'spacetime fabric'. LIGO detects interferences while the MM experiment didn't detect any. In one case we speak of the spacetime fabric in the other case the universe is empty. Isn't it a contradiction?

Comment: If you want more information about LIGO, the public LIGO [Document Control Center](http://dcc.ligo.org/cgi-bin/DocDB/DocumentDatabase) makes LIGO design documents available, including some [conceptual design documents](http://dcc.ligo.org/cgi-bin/DocDB/ListBy?topicid=21). For example, [How to build a Gravitational-wave Detector](http://dcc.ligo.org/public/0006/G0900960/001/G0900960-v1.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is that the Michelson-Morley apparatus was made as rigid as feasible to prevent geometric distortion. LIGO, with its optics suspended on pendula, is as un-rigid as feasible, as changes in its geometry are how it senses gravitational waves.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar experiments in that they both make use of interferometers, however, they are designed to accomplish different goals.

The Michelson-Morley experiment was designed such that interference would indicate light travelling at different rates due to the motion of the ether. The size of the Michelson-Morley interferometer was much to small to be able to detect gravitational waves. On the other hand, the LIGO experiment is designed such that interference is an indicator that the light travelling down each arm of the interferometer has covered different distances (due to a passing gravitational wave).

So apart from using the same tool, these two experiments are very different. Furthermore, because they test completely different regimes, seeing and interference in one but not the other is NOT a contradiction.